# Sending H264 encoded .mov file over UDP to client on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, avfoundation

The whole ios video sending/streaming paradigm seems to be a bit vague and uncovered. The task I am trying to perform is similar to that of how videos are played for clients when watching a YouTube videos.

What I am trying to essentially do is quite simple:

1. I have a pre-made encoded .mov file on my server.
2. I want to send
       that file through a UDP socket to a client.

Here is where I am getting lost:

1. How do I break down the .mov file to correctly send it over the
   socket? Do I need to break down into frames? If so, how?

Right now I am creating an NSData object from the file and breaking it into chunks which I send over the socket like so:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      URLForResource:@"test1" withExtension:@"mov"];
NSData *newData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];

int index = 0;
int totalLen = (int)[newData length];

while (index < totalLen) {

    int space = (totalLen - index > 9216) ? 9216 : totalLen - index;
    NSData *chunk = [newData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, space)];
    [udpSocket sendData:chunk toAddress:clientAddress withTimeout:-1 tag:2];
    index += 9216;

}
```

2. On the client-side, how do I receive and play these packets? 
   At the moment I'm combining all of the incoming data and concatenating it into one big NSData file which I'd like to play once all of the data is received (which intuitively seems to me like the wrong way to approach this):

   ```
   - (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
     fromAddress:(NSData *)address withFilterContext:(id)filterContext{

   /* Append nsdata packets from socket until all the file has been received */
   [videoData appendData:data];


   if([data length] < 9216){
       /* Marks EOF. Start playing the video */
       [self playVideoData];
   }
   ```

Then playing the video...

```
    -(void)playVideoData{

    NSURL* fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] init];
    [videoData writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];

    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:fileURL options:nil];

    NSString *tracksKey = @"tracks";

    /** Normal AVURLAsset video playing here... */

    }
```